# If else statement is giving wrong output

Tags: java, swing, validation, if-statement, focuslistener

Im trying to add validation on my textbox in my code by using if else condition

Ive added focusListener on the textbox that will check the condition  when I remove the focus from textbox
Ive also created a label beside the chekbox which will display text according to the condition

***If the text inside the textbox is not equal to "hi" then it should print "hello" in the label beside textbox***

***otherwise it should print "bye"***

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class regframe extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JTextField t1,t2;
    JLabel l1,l2,l3,l4;
    JButton b;

    regframe()
    {   
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        l1=new JLabel("Enter First Num:");
        l1.setBounds(50,50,150,20);
        l1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        l1.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        add(l1);

        t1=new JTextField();
        t1.setBounds(180,50,100,20);
        t1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        t1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        t1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0,Color.YELLOW));
        t1.setCaretColor(Color.CYAN);
        t1.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        t1.addActionListener(this);
        add(t1);
        
        l3=new JLabel();
        l3.setBounds(290,50,150,20);
        l3.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
        l3.setOpaque(false);
        l3.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,10));
        add(l3);

        t1.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() 
        {
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
            {
                if(t1.getText()!="hi")
                {
                    l3.setText("hello");
                }
                else
                {
                    l3.setText("bye");
                }
            }
        });
        

        l2=new JLabel("Enter Second Num:");
        l2.setBounds(50,80,150,20);
        l2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        l2.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        add(l2);        

        t2=new JTextField();
        t2.setBounds(180,80,100,20);
        t2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        t2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        t2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0,Color.YELLOW));
        t2.setCaretColor(Color.CYAN);
        t2.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,12));
        add(t2);
                
        b=new JButton("Submit");
        b.setBounds(100,120,100,20);
        b.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            b.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        add(b);

        setLocation(300,200);
        setSize(700,250);
        setLayout(null);
        setTitle("Registration");
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new regframe();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        
        
    }
}
```

But when I run the code, It always display "hello" even when I write "hi" inside the textbox
[image]

[image]

Please Help

Comment: @JavaMan already solved my problem.But still thank you for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
if(!"hi".equals(t1.getText())
```

instead of

```
if(t1.getText()!="hi")
```

You could also do `if(!t1.getText().equals("hi"))`
but the other method is more null-safe

Take a look at https://www.javatpoint.com/string-comparison-in-java

Comment: (1+) I like the idea of invoking the equals() method on the string constant so you don't have to worry about the getText() method returning null.

Comment: Its working wow that I've made the changes you suggested.Thank you!